# Format code with Allman style applied to parenthesis spanning across lines

Tags: intellij-idea

I have this code, as formatted using my current settings:

```
super
    (
            new Stuff
                    (
                            new Stuff(),
                            new Stuff(),
                            new Stuff()
                    )
    );
```

But I want it to come out as:

```
super
(
    new Stuff
    (
        new Stuff(),
        new Stuff(),
        new Stuff()
    )
);
```

When I hit Ctrl+Alt+L to format the code. I want the parenthesis nested stuff like this to follow the Allman style. Wrapped lines are set to use two indent tabs, which I might have to reduce to 1. Would I have to lose the ability for wrapped code statements to be indented using 2 tabs?
What about the leading and trailing start and end of the parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment IntelliJ IDEA uses hardcoded continuation indent for the braces, there is no configuration that will format it as you need. [Request is welcome](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).